# A local IP address (RFC 1918) on my network that is not … local

Tags: networking, routing, ip, router, tcpip

I've noticed an IP address today on my network (192.168.15.1) which when visited actually goes to a page that has a router webconfig page (Not **my** router)

The puzzling thing is that i tried `traceroute 192.168.15.1` which said that the distance between me and that host is 9 hops, whereas the distance between me and any other computer on my home network is 2 hops away
(My computer --> Router --> Host)

Can someone please explain what's going on here ?

tracert output:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.15.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    47 ms    51 ms    49 ms  [163.121.171.123]
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4   128 ms     *        *     163.121.211.134.dnet.net [163.121.211.134
]
  5     *      134 ms   126 ms  10.37.242.18
  6    94 ms    90 ms    95 ms  10.35.2.157
  7   178 ms   254 ms   206 ms  10.32.8.107
  8    85 ms    57 ms   318 ms  10.35.0.186
  9   215 ms   241 ms   230 ms  192.168.15.1

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Too many things that it could be, and we are not a network troubleshooting forum.  Interesting puzzle, though.

Comment: If you aren't in Cairo, Egypt (and I suspect you are not) then your ISP has done something horribly wrong. If you _are_ in Cairo, Egypt, then your ISP has done something completely different but equally horribly wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Care to elaborate ?

Comment: Unless you want to elaborate on your circumstances, [this](http://serverfault.com/q/520952/126632) is all I can offer you.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the MAC, resolving the hostname, and using OS fingerprinting to give yourself some more clues.

Comment: Tried to do all that, haven't found a record for in the `arp -a` output, nslookup and nbtstat won't resolve it because it's "Host not found"

Answer (score 2):

Your subnet mask is undoubtedly 255.255.255.0, so that address is not on your network.  If your subnet mask is 255.255.0.0, your machine wouldn't be sending traffic to it through your gateway.

Comment: But aren't these /16 addresses local as well (RFC 1918) ?
Still doesn't make sense..

Comment: Forget the RFCs.  They were written when the Internet was a small network connecting universities and gov't labs, and subnet masks have been applied differently to make it work in the real world of today..  Is every 10.x.x.x network going to have a subnet mask of 255.0.0.0?  No.  None are because it would result in 255*255*255 network addresses on one subnet.  As some of the other comments mention, your ISP, though, should really not have a route to a 192.168.x.x address.  It is probably a tech that plugged in a router, and the auto-discovery on the routers has made it routable to you.

Comment: If you contact your ISP, be ready to waste a huge amount of time convincing them that you aren't nuts.  And even if you get past that, they may not care unless it's causing a problem.

Comment: I don't understand, How can a 192.168.x.x address point to somewhere outside the local network ?!

Comment: That's not something that can be explosioned in a few sentences.  Plus, what you need to understand is well documented.  Search for tutorials on IP routing.  A 192.168 address can be routed just like any other address, and since that address is on a different subnet, it's not local to you.